# How Can I Expand The GPIO / Pin Quantity When A PiSound is Installed on the RPI4?

Tags: gpio, pi-4, electronics

I'm working on creating a musical synthesizer and the sound engine requires a Raspberry Pi 4 + PiSound. From what I can gather, the PiSound is placed right on top of the RPI4 and uses its GPIO pins.

What I'm building requires 96 pins. How would I be able to expand the quantity of available pins on my Pi4 whilst also being able to continue making use of the PiSound?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly MCP23017 port expander chips.